# cross domain Jquery call Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: jquery

I am making a cross domain call to my REST Service  using Jquery mobile as shown below , 
but i am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` in console .

could anybody please tell me whether how can i make a cross domain call .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  


<button id="json">json</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#json').click(function(){ 

 dataType: 'jsonp',
crossDomain: true,
         $.getJSON("http://localhost:8086/Services/ajax/vendors",
         function(data) {
            alert(data);         
          });   
    });


</script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: whats your response look like?

Comment: I have a JSON response as shown below ["Poppy Counter","Mahalakshmi Counter","sai Services"]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `jsonp`, server should wrap the response to a function.

For example, if you want to return the response `{"id":1}`.
Then your server response should look like,

```
someFunction({"id":1})
```

Then in your client side code,

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'http://localhost:8086/Services/ajax/vendors',
     dataType: 'jsonp',

 });

 function someFunction(data)
 { 
     alert(data)
  }
```